# Auto incremented column scoped to user id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am really struggling how to implement requirement which is going to be best described with example.
Consider everything below to be written in pseudocode although I am interested in solutions for postgres.

| id | id_for_user | note | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Buy milk | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Winter tyres | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | Read for 1h | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Clean dishes | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | Learn how magnets work | 2 |

```sql
INSERT INTO notes VALUES (note: 'Learn icelandic', created_by: 1);
```

| id | id_for_user | note | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Buy milk | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | Winter tyres | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | Read for 1h | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | Clean dishes | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | Learn how magnets work | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | Learn Icelandic | 1 |

```sql
INSERT INTO notes VALUES (note: 'Are birds real?', created_by: 2);
```

| id | id_for_user | note | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Buy milk | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | Winter tyres | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | Read for 1h | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | Clean dishes | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | Learn how magnets work | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | Learn Icelandic | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | Are birds real? | 2 |

I would like to achieve something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE notes (
    id SERIAL,
    id_for_user INT DEFAULT nextval(created_by) -- Dynamic name for sequence so every user gets its own,
    note VARCHAR,
    created_by INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, id_for_user),
    CONSTRAINT fk_notes_created_by
      FOREIGN KEY(created_by) 
        REFERENCES users(created_by)
);
```

So that user `1` sees (notice how `id_for_user` is just `id` on front end)

| id | note |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Buy milk |
| 2 | Winter tyres |
| 3 | Read for 1h |
| 4 | Learn Icelandic |

And user `2`

| id | note |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Clean dishes |
| 2 | Learn how magnets work |
| 3 | Are birds real? |

Basically I want to have auto incremented field for each user.
I am then also probably going to query for the record by `id_for_user` filling `create_by` on backend based on which user made the request.

Is something like this even possible? What are my options? I would really like to have this logic on db level.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6eBvq4VCQPTmmR3W6fCnEm/2

Comment: That is not how auto-incremented columns work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good to know if you ignore that what solution would you recommend?

Comment: You can have a separate table to store "the last ID for each user". Then a trigger can fill the value and increment the related table. Are inserts multi-threaded? If that's the case you'll need to add some isolation (pessimistic or optimistic locking).

Comment: @TheImpaler I find it hard to believe there is no easy solution but I am no db expert. Couldn't we take advantage of me having `created_at` column I forgot to mention? You know in which order the records were inserted and calculate new `id_for_user` somehow maybe?

Comment: @Hnus It's easy to compute the value on the fly while querying the table: a simple `ROW_NUMBER()` window function will do the trick. I thought you wanted to persist the new ID while inserting.

Comment: @Hnus . . . I would have an identity column and generate the sequential number in queries.

Comment: @TheImpaler I would like to have it done when inserting. I guess my best bet is trigger. Could you please help me with my attempt at doing so? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=286d573f85110578fd24ca23102b19c0 you can then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a sequence, this object will have control of the autonumeric of the ID

example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_notes1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 100;

  CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_notes2
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 100;

CREATE TABLE notes (
  id SERIAL,
  id_for_user INT,
  note VARCHAR,
  created_by INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


INSERT INTO notes (id_for_user, note, created_by) VALUES (nextval('sequence_notes1'),'Foo', 1);
INSERT INTO notes (id_for_user, note, created_by) VALUES (nextval('sequence_notes1'),'Moo', 1);
INSERT INTO notes (id_for_user, note, created_by) VALUES (nextval('sequence_notes2'),'Boo', 2);
INSERT INTO notes (id_for_user, note, created_by) VALUES (nextval('sequence_notes2'),'Loo', 2);
```

Comment: I don't think that works https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6eBvq4VCQPTmmR3W6fCnEm/1

Comment: If its postgres it works for autoincremental, I used this type of configurations in a DB

Comment: I provided runnable example of your suggestion where it clearly doesn't work.

Comment: I undertand, my example is for general autonumeric, but you need for user, let me think in another sugestion

Comment: If the input is with code and variables, you can use two sequences and use the sequence that depends of an user, in the example I use the sequence  "sequence_notes1" for user 1 and "sequence_notes2" for de user 2, then set the secuance for each case. this case is manual, but if run with code may be dynamic with variables

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate table to store "the next ordinal value for each user". Then a trigger can fill the value and increment the related table.

For example:

```
create table usr (
  id int primary key,
  next_ordinal int default 1
);

create table note (
  id int primary key,
  note varchar(100),
  created_by int references usr (id),
  user_ord int
);

create or replace function add_user_ord() returns trigger as $$
begin
  select next_ordinal into new.user_ord from usr where id = new.created_by;
  update usr set next_ordinal = next_ordinal + 1 where id = new.created_by;
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
//

create trigger trg_note1 before insert on note 
for each row execute procedure add_user_ord();
```

Then, the trigger will add the correct ordinal numbers automatically behind the scenes during `INSERT`s:

```
insert into usr (id) values (10), (20);

insert into note (id, note, created_by) values (1, 'Hello', 10);
insert into note (id, note, created_by) values (2, 'Lorem', 20);
insert into note (id, note, created_by) values (3, 'World', 10);
insert into note (id, note, created_by) values (4, 'Ipsum', 20);
```

Result:

```
id  note   created_by  user_ord
--  -----  ----------  --------
 1  Hello          10         1
 2  Lorem          20         1
 3  World          10         2
 4  Ipsum          20         2
```

**Note**: This solution does not address multi-threading inserts. If your application needs this you'll need to add some isolation (or pessimistic, or optimistic locking) for it.

Comment: How does it compare to my now functioning trigger? I don't know why I should store this data in new table when the information is already there it just needs to be calculated? I don't know if the multi-threaded inserts are still relevant but this is something I will probably go with https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=39d4388d1d3853e18c434d8dde43f036

Comment: @Hnus Your solution works. However, it has two potential drawbacks that may or may not be important to you: 1) Your solution and mine don't handle multi-threading inserts; this needs to be resolved if you have mutliple threads inserting. 2) Your solution can become gradually slower when the table grows; I would suggest you add the index `(created_by, id_for_user)` so the trigger runs fast.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, this is supported in the MyISAM storage engine.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html says:

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary
> column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value
> for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as
> MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is
> useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE animals (
>     grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
>     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
>
> INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
>     ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
>     ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
>     ('bird','ostrich');
> ```
>
> SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id; Which returns:
>
> ```
> +--------+----+---------+
> | grp    | id | name    |
> +--------+----+---------+
> | fish   |  1 | lax     |
> | mammal |  1 | dog     |
> | mammal |  2 | cat     |
> | mammal |  3 | whale   |
> | bird   |  1 | penguin |
> | bird   |  2 | ostrich |
> +--------+----+---------+
> ```

The reason this works in MyISAM is that MyISAM only supports table-level locking.

In a storage engine with row-level locking, you get race conditions if you try to have a primary key that works like this. This is why others on this thread have commented that implementing this with triggers requires some pessimistic locking. You have to use locking to ensure that only one client at a time is inserting, so they don't allocate the same value.

This will be limiting in a high-traffic application. InnoDB's auto-increment is implemented the way it is to allow applications in which many client threads are executing inserts concurrently.

So you could use MyISAM or you could use InnoDB and invent your own way of allocating new id's per user, but either way it will severely limit your app's scalability.